# React Redux Router pass props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

i've this App.js

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
   isPeddingHome: state.getShowsHome.isPeddingHome,
   data: state.getShowsHome.data,
   isPeddingMovies: state.getShowsMovies.isPeddingMovies,
   movies: state.getShowsMovies.movies,
   isPeddingSeries: state.getShowsTv.isPeddingSeries,
   series: state.getShowsTv.series
 }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return {
  onGetShows: () => dispatch(getShows()),
  onGetMovies: () => dispatch(getMovies()),
  onGetSeries: () => dispatch(getTvSeries())
 }
}

const App = () =>  {
 return (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/"  component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/movies" component={MoviesPage}/>
      <Route path="/tv" component={tvSeriesPage}/>
     </Switch>
   </Router>
 );
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

i want to pass props from that i create with mapStateToProps, example

on Home pass only data, isPeddingHome and onGetShows, it's posssible?

i try to use

```
render={(props) => <Home {...props} />}
```

to pass but not pass nothing to component

Comment: how your store looks like?

Comment: Why not directly connect components to data they need?

Comment: use connect directly inside the components...

Comment: const rootReducers = combineReducers({getShowsHome, getShowsMovies, getShowsTv});

const logger = createLogger();
const store = createStore(rootReducers, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, logger));

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}> <App /> </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: i used to connect directly i think this way can be more clean the code, but if it's not possible i reuse to connect directly on the compoent the store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument passed to the `render` prop function are the [`route props`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props), not the props given to the `App` component.

You can spread the `App` props and the route props as well to get what you want.

```
const App = props => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          render={routeProps => <Home {...props} {...routeProps} />}
        />
        <Route path="/movies" component={MoviesPage} />
        <Route path="/tv" component={tvSeriesPage} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The props argument to render prop callback is the router props and no the component props, you need to change your code to pass the props to `App` component to `Home` component.

```
const App = (props) =>  {
 return (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/"  render={(routerProps) => <Home data={props.data} onGetShows={props.onGetShows} isPeddingMovies={props. isPeddingMovies} {...routerProps}/>}/>
      <Route path="/movies" component={MoviesPage}/>
      <Route path="/tv" component={tvSeriesPage}/>
     </Switch>
   </Router>
 );
}
```

You can choose to destructure the props in App.js and pass them on to Home like

```
const App = ({isPeddingMovies, onGetShows, data}) =>  {
 return (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/"  render={(routerProps) => <Home data={data} onGetShows={onGetShows} isPeddingMovies={isPeddingMovies} {...routerProps}/>}/>
      <Route path="/movies" component={MoviesPage}/>
      <Route path="/tv" component={tvSeriesPage}/>
     </Switch>
   </Router>
 );
}
```

However since the App component is not consuming all the props from `mapStateToProps` or `mapDispatchToProps` you can simply connect the Home component

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
   isPeddingHome: state.getShowsHome.isPeddingHome,
   data: state.getShowsHome.data,
   isPeddingMovies: state.getShowsMovies.isPeddingMovies,
 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```